# Avoid Repeating Oneself When Doing A Select From IEnumerable

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, xelement

I have an `IEumerable<XElement>` called `foo`.

I have this code

```
foo.Select(x => new
        {
            bars = x.Descendants(namespace + "bar") != null 
                ? x.Descendants(namespace + "bar").Select(z => z.Value).ToArray() 
                : new string[0]
        })
        .ToArray();
```

How can I write this a little neater?  I really don't want to repeat this part

```
x.Descendants(namespace + "bar")
```

Comment: use a variable and reuse it

Comment: Once C# 6 is out, you can use the [null conditional](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/825488/New-Features-in-Csharp-Null-Conditional-Operator) operator `?.`.

Comment: Does Descendants return NULL? its a deferred enumerable? surely it will be always present, it just might be empty

Comment: @Richard Yes, actually, it will.  Just like the null coalescing operator it won't evaluate any of the operands multiple times.

Comment: Why are you projecting the items into an anonymous type with only one property?  Why not just project to a sequence of strings directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using an additional `Select`:

```
foo.Select(x => x.Descendants(namespace + "bar"))
   .Select(x => new
            {
                bars = x != null ? x.Select(z => z.Value).ToArray() : new string[0]
            })
            .ToArray();
```

Or:

```
foo.Select(x =>
               {
                   var elements = x.Descendants(namespace + "bar");
                   return new
                   {
                      bars = elements != null ? elements.Select(z => z.Value).ToArray() : new string[0]
                   }
                })
            .ToArray();
```

**BTW**, I don't think `Descendants` will return *null*.You should probably check whether there are any elements using `Any` method.

```
 bars = x.Any() ? x.Select(z => z.Value).ToArray() : new string[0]
```

Comment: Or Just x.Select(x => x.Value).ToArray().  Any() is not needed

Answer (score 1):

You could use a different lambda expression to avoid repetition as follows, where you can also implement the null check.

```
Function<XElement,IEnumerable<XElement>> f =
    x =>  x.Descendants(namespace + "bar") ?? Enumerable.Empty<XElement>():

foo.Select(x => new 
            {
                f(x).Select(z => z.Value).ToArray();
            })
            .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foo.Select(x => new
    {
        bars = x.Descendants(namespace + "bar") != null 
            ? x.Descendants(namespace + "bar").Select(z => z.Value).ToArray() 
            : new string[0]
    })
    .ToArray();
```

> How can I write this a little neater? I really don't want to repeat
>   this part

```
foo.Select(x => new { bars = x.Descendants(namespace + "bar")
                              .Select(z => z.Value).ToArray()}).ToArray();
```

You don't need to check for NULL as Descendants returns a deferred enumerable,  e.g, it will always have an instance of IEnumerable, it may be empty ( no results ), but the **.Select(z => z.Value).ToArray()** will automatically produce new **string[0] { }** if there are no results.

Comment: You need to explain why this solution is appropriate and a valid translation of the OP's code.